# The opens directive in Java 9

Tags: java, java-9

I'm reading the draft of the Java 9 specification but this phrase is not clear to me:

> The opens directive specifies the name of a package to be opened by the current module. This makes public and protected types in the package, and their public and protected members, be accessible to code in other modules at run time only. It also makes all types in the package, and all their members, be accessible via the reflection libraries of the Java SE Platform.

If the opens makes public and protected accessible at runtime only, what does meaning that all types in the packages area accessible via reflection?

I don't understand the difference between runtime and reflection.

It seems like the opened package makes accessible only public and protected at runtime (via reflection?) and also other packages not specified with type and members accessible vie reflection (also private...).

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question correctly but, consider that someone might have code that depends on the public API in a package. Then Java 9 comes out and the package is encapsulated inside a module. You would need to open the module in order to keep using that legacy code.

Comment: I try to explain again: if open allows all type and all members of a package to be reflective accessed why is there a public and protected case explained?

Comment: Ok thanks. Well like I said, it could be that someone was using those APIs (the normal way, not via reflection) before the package is encapsulated. It seems to be a backwards compatibility feature.

Comment: Excuse me how can be possible to access the API (public and protected) at runtime without the reflection? (an opened package is not accessible at compile time...). Maybe public and protected will be accessed with normal reflection while private with deep reflection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's say you write some code that uses a public class from a library.

```
import somelibrary.somepackage.SomeClass; // <-- public class from a library.

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeClass.doSomething();
    }

}
```

You then compile this code, and it compiles fine, since the class you're using is `public`.

Now, in the next version of the library, the package is added to a module, but not exported. That means that if you try to run your code with this new module on the runtime module path, it would throw an exception because you're trying to access an encapsulated package.

In order to make your code work again, you could use the command line option to open this module to your code, so that it can continue to use the encapsulated package.

Alternatively, the creator of the library could add `opens somepackage;` to the module definition of the library. That would allow you to *run* your code using this new version, but not *compile* with it. I.e. the `public` and `protected` members are only accessible at runtime, but there is no reflection involved.

---

The same goes for when you extend a class, and want to access a `protected` member of a super class that is in the encapsulated package.

But the opens directive does not change the fact that, if in the next version of a library, a method or field is made `private`, that you get an `IllegalAccessError` if you try to use it:

```
class SomeClass { // <-- the class in the library
    public static void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("doSomething"); // contrived example code
    }
}
```

...

```
public class Main {    
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {      
        SomeClass.doSomething(); // this call compiles fine,
    }    
}
```

Then, in the next version of the library `doSomething` is made `private`:

```
private static void doSomething() {...}
```

And re-compiled. But if you try to run the old version of `Main` with the new version of `SomeClass` you get an `IllegalAccessError`.

In short, opens only works for members that are still `public` or `protected` in the new version of the library.

---

However, in the case of reflection, you can always access a `private` member, by using `setAccessible(true)`:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {      
    Method m = SomeClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("doSomething");
    m.setAccessible(true);
    m.invoke(null); // works Fine
}
```

So in the case of reflection, opens would also make encapsulated private members accessible again.

Comment: Yes, this is a good answer so I up voted but in this case I can also access to private members... so again I don't understand the differences expressed into the specification. Sincerely is cleared what is said in documentation posted by @xenteros but in the same time I don't think the specification is in error.... also if it is in draft!

Comment: @xdevel2000 No, you can't access `private` members in this case (where you compile against a `public` API, that is made `private` in a later version). You would get an `IllegalAccessError`, and using opens wouldn't change that.

Comment: Please, can you provide me a complete example of the IllegalAccessError? Now I can't try this by myself... If you can, of course :)

Comment: @xdevel2000 I added some examples, hope it helps :)

Comment: @JornVernee stupid question? Where is the directive used in your examples?

Comment: @xenteros I don't use it here explicitly, but it could be used as a command line option when running `Main` when the module containing the package with `SomeClass` no longer exports that package. i.e. `--add-opens com.mylib/com.mylib=main` where main is the depending module, `com.mylib` the dependency module, and `com.mylib` the package with `SomeClass`. Or, alternatively (this doesn't really fit my example), it could be used like `opens com.mylib to main;` from the `module-info.java` of `com.mylib`.

Answer (score 3):

> A package opened by a module, may be qualified or unqualified.
>
> The opens directive in a module declaration declares a package to be
>   open to allow all types in the package, and all their members, not
>   just public types and their public members to be reflected on by APIs
>   that support private access or a way to bypass or suppress default
>   Java language access control checks.

[--Documentation](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleDescriptor.Opens.html)

Comment: Good... so it seems in contradiction with the specification... maybe because is it in draft?